# ArrayAdapter NullPointerException in BroadcastReceiver onReceive

Tags: android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver, android-arrayadapter

I have an activity where I'm using an ArrayAdapter that is declared in the class body itself:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> btDevArrayAdapter = null;
```

in my onCreate() function I do the following:

```
    ListView btDevList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.btList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> btDevArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    btDevList.setAdapter(btDevArrayAdapter);
    btDevArrayAdapter.add("test");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

    if (btDevArrayAdapter==null) {
        Log.d("ARRAY ADAPTER ON CREATE"," I AM NULL");
    } else {
        Log.d("ARRAY ADAPTER"," I AM INITIALIZED "); //this always shows up
    }
```

later on, I register a broadcast receiver

```
   registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

and start bluetooth device discovery

```
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

the `BroadcastReceiver` is also declared in the class body:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            if (btDevArrayAdapter==null) {
                Log.d("ARRAY ADAPTER"," I AM NULL"); // <-- NullPointerException
            } else {
                if (device == null)
                    btDevArrayAdapter.add("was null!");
                else
                    btDevArrayAdapter.add(device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Looking at my logcat, it always looks like this:

`01-01 02:34:02.200: D/ARRAY ADAPTER(1745):  I AM INITIALIZED`

01-01 02:34:05.393: D/ARRAY ADAPTER(1745):  I AM NULL

What could cause the ArrayAdapter to become null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the NPE becouse you initiate a adapter which is only visible in the onCreate method here:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> btDevArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

change it to this:

```
btDevArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

inside your onCreate-Method.